# setting div as a background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div like which has an background, i like to set this div as an transparent background to certain dialog, like a jquery dialog. But the issue here is when the user scrolls the transparent div is also moving. i want this transparent div to be fixed even the scroll bar   moves. How can i achieve this? Thanks.

**Sample Code:**

doc is an instance of html document. [doc  instanceof HTMLDocument]

```
<div id=hiox1002  align=center style='display: none; z-index:3;opacity:0.4;\
            filter:alpha(opacity=40);background-image:url(http://funflys.com/images/bg.png);background-repeat:repeat;\
            width: "+doc.defaultView.innerWidth+"px; height: "+doc.defaultView.innerHeight+"px;/></div>
```

I am trying this for an firefox add on

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `position:fixed` style.

Comment: i tried that and it should've worked but in my case it is not working , is it due to am taking width and height from "doc" object

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't worked for me, but i made it in other way.i've removed scrollbars and denied actions for arrows keys. take a look @ this code: doc.body.style.overflow=''; and in key press event i coded like 'e.preventDefault()' . it worked for me....

Comment: @Sekar - this should work:
<div id=hiox1002 align=center style="display: none; z-index:3;opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40);background-image:url(http://funflys.com/images/bg.png);background-repeat:repeat; width: 200px; height: 200px; `position: fixed`"/></div>

Comment: yes ari it worked, but not as i wished, i need to set this div height and width to whole screen. because i'm using this for firefox addon i tried create an object for htmldocument and set the div width and height using this doc object, in that case it is not working properly. Thanks for your information ari.

Comment: @Sekar - the width and height that I used above are just placeholders. You should replace them with the values you'd specified in the OP

Answer (score 0):

add `position:fixed` in your css..and have a look on this [**tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)